# PHP json_encode displays empty string from mySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I did some research and it turns out this can happen if the string isn't in UTF8 format.

However, after a lot of testing, I can say that it is indeed in UTF8 (or at least I know with 100% certainty it's in ASCII format) so clearly, this cannot be it.

Are there any other qualifiers that need to be met with `json_encode`?

Here is my code;

```
  for($i=0; $i<$addNovelCount; $i++) {
    $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM `NovelPages` 
              WHERE `NovelID` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $novelResults[$i])."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       $Novel[] = $row['Image'];
       $NovelID[] = $row['NovelID'];
       $PageID[] = $row['ID'];
    }
  }

  echo '<script>alert("'.json_encode($PageID).'");</script>';
```

Comment: First check that the array `$PageID` actually contains something. I knwo its a long shot but if the query returns no rows then `$PageID` will be empty. ALSO What is in `$addNovelCount` is that is 0 then the outer loop will never be run

Comment: @RiggsFolly $PageID returens 2 elements, both numbers. I opened the browser console and got a bunch of error messages saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" followed by " at p (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Ja (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    --- for example, there are more. BTW thals for the injection attack heads up

Comment: `json_encode` already adds outer quotes if needed. There's no point in wrapping it in the alert() call. Also, instead of guessing the problem, look at the real HTML output.

Comment: @mario what do you mean real HTML output?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is bad news user9391457 like @RiggsFolly pointed out, the function is meant to be used on a SQL string, on INT datatype which i assume is NovelID is it might mess up MySQL for ever using a index on that column if the auto casting is messing up.. Besides the function is not safe without setting a default charset with `mysqli_set_charset()` it's in the manual..

Comment: Your browser, right click page, view source.

Comment: @RaymondNijland So what would you recommend I use?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem and it is so simple and anticlimactic I want to die... Especially that I spent multiple days researching this!

It turns out the reason it was that I was putting json in quotes which created double quotes in the array, breaking the syntax. This threw me off because I was using alert as a way to debug the real thing I was trying to fix which was using json to place a php variable in a javascript cookie but instead of...

```
$linkSearchCacheJson = json_encode($linkSearchCacheCleared);

echo'
    <script>
        var cookieVar = '.$linkSearchCacheJson.';
        alert(cookieVar);
        document.cookie = "linkSearchCache = " + cookieVar;
    </script>
';
```

I was doing...

```
echo'
    <script>
        document.cookie = "linkSearchCache = '.json_encode($linkSearchCacheCleared).'";
    </script>
';
```

Which was breaking the syntax (again) because it was placing double quotes inside double quotes.

Moral of the story; json_encode wraps the variable in double quotes.

Comment: Instead of `echo` with a bunch of string concatenation, just `?><script>...<?php echo json_encode(...) ?>...<?php` and so on. The key here is that JSON uses double quotes, so you can't double quote a JSON string without additional escaping.

Answer (score -2):

you cant alert the json_encoded data or array of data, try to console.log the result
hope this will solve your problem.

```
 echo '<script>console.log("'.json_encode($PageID).'");</script>';
```

Comment: yes you can, you just don't add the outside double quotes